# Asp.Net Mvc pull selected value from ViewData based dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple form in Asp.Net MVC form and I had a dropdown list with values pulled from a view data.
How can I get the value of selected value from dropdown to the controller object to use inside httppost method?

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemType)
@Html.DropDownList("ItemTypes", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["itemTypes"], "Value", "Text"))

<input type="submit" value="Request Item" />


ViewData["itemTypes"] = GetItemTypes();
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewVc(ItemInfoViewModel itemInfoObject)
    {
    //Item not populated to itemInfoObject
    }
```

Pull Item types from

```
 public static List<ListItem> GetItemTypes()
        {
            var itemTypes = new List<ListItem>
            {
                new ListItem {Text = "Select", Value = ""},
                new ListItem {Text = "Item1", Value = "Item1"},
                new ListItem {Text = "Item2", Value = "Item2"},
                new ListItem {Text = "Item3", Value = "Item3"}
            };
            return itemTypes;
        }
```

Comment: Does your `ItemInfoViewModel` contain a property named `ItemTypes` (but in any case do not use the same name for the property your bind to and the name of the `SelectList`)

Comment: My viewmodel has the property

Comment: Then assuming its `string ItemTypes` it will be bound with the selected option value. But this is awful practice and you should be using a view model with properties `string `SelectedItemType` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemTypeList` and using the strongly typed `@Html.DropDowmListFor(m => m.SelectedItemType, Model.ItemTypeList)`

Comment: Based on your `Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemType)` you model contains a property named `ItemType` (which is not the same as `ItemTypes` - plural)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not exist, add a new property to store the selected option

```
public class ItemInfoViewModel 
{
  public string SelectedItemType { set;get;}
  // your existing properties
}
```

Now in your GET action method, you can use the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper inside the form.

```
@model ItemInfoViewModel 
@using(Html.BeginForm("NewVc","PutYourControllerNameHere"))
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedItemType, 
                                           ViewData["itemTypes"] as List<SelectListItem>)
   <input type="submit" />

}
```

*Replace PutYourControllerNameHere with your actual controller name where you have the `NewVc` action method. You do not need the `Controller` Suffix.*

The above code basically generates the HTML tag for a SELECT element with name "`SelectItemType`" inside a `form` tag. When you submit the form, model binder will be able to map the posted form data to the property of your `ItemInfoViewModel` object, which is the parameter of your HttpPost action method.

Also you should change the return type of 
your `GetItemTypes` method to a collection of `SelectListItem` since our view code is trying to cast it directly a `List<SelectListItem>`

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetItemTypes()
{
        var itemTypes = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Select", Value = ""},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Item1", Value = "Item1"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Item2", Value = "Item2"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Item3", Value = "Item3"}
        };
        return itemTypes;
 }
```

Comment: This throws error Compiler Error Message: CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: Sorry ! I did not pay attention to your `GetItemTypes` method. See the edit in answer..

Comment: awesome worked like a charm. Changes did for community reference:
1. SelectListItem 2. DropdownListFor